# Turn off reveal brush effect of calendar view in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to edit some design elements of calendar view in UWP.
Below is picture of calendar view.

[image]

And I've tried to turn off reveal brush effect which appears at border of element box itself and surrounded element box, but fails.

I want to make calendar that looks like calendar of Appointment app has.
It has two calendar and two of them don't have reveal brush.
[image]
I edited the template of `CalendarViewDayItemRevealStyle`, but It doesn't work.

#### Added

following source is original source of template. I removed setter of Point over state, but reveal brush isn't removed.

```
 <Style x:Key="CalendarViewDayItemRevealStyle" TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="40"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0, 0, 0, 4"/>
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-2"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="Root" Width="0">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="PointOver"/>
                                        <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Target="Root.(RevealBrush.State)" Value="Pressed"/>
                                        <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBackgroundPressed}" />
                                        <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="CalendarViewCalendarViewDayItemStyle1" 
           BasedOn="{StaticResource CalendarViewDayItemRevealStyle}" 
           TargetType="CalendarViewDayItem"/>
```

How can I remove reveal brush effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the default style for CalendarView in `generic.xaml` file, you will see it has specified two extra reveal brush for `CalendarItem`.

```
<Setter Property="CalendarItemForeground" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarViewCalendarItemForeground}" />
<Setter Property="CalendarItemBackground" Value="{ThemeResource CalendarViewCalendarItemRevealBackground}" />
```

You could change it like the following:

```
<CalendarView CalendarItemBackground="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAltHighBrush}"  CalendarItemBorderBrush="Gray"></CalendarView>
```

Then, the reveal effect will disappear.

> For design purposes, generic.xaml is available in the `\(Program Files)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\xxxx\Generic` folder from a Windows SDK installation.

Comment: Your answer solves my problem. and I'm sorry that I have a question about  `CalendarViewDayItemRevealStyle`. If I choose not to use `CalendarViewCalendarItemRevealBackground`, then what does this effect on `CalendarView`? and If this does not effect on visual part of `CalendarView` by changinc `CalendarViewDayItemRevealStyle`, then by removing Setter `PointOver` of `CalendarViewDayItemRevealStyle`, Can I get any profit on visual calculation of App?.

Comment: If you remove the whole <Grid x:Name="Root" Width="0"> in CalendarViewDayItemRevealStyle, you may get a little bit of performance improvement. I don't expect any change if you only remove PointerOver. Maybe very minor performance improvement(actually you can't see it) if you are not using CalendarViewCalendarItemRevealBackground, and I don't expect any other impact on CalendarView. In conclusion, you will not get a profit when re-template CalendarViewDayItemRevealStyle, but may introduce problem in the future os since CalendarViewDayItemRevealStyle is evolving

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use CalendarViewCalendarItemBackground as ItemBackground. I didn't see 
CalendarViewCalendarItemBorderBrush, maybe it works if we set ItemBorderBrush to null.

```
<CalendarView CalendarItemBackground="{ThemeResource CalendarViewCalendarItemBackground}"  CalendarItemBorderBrush="{x:Null}"></CalendarView>
```